# Catching the returned value

Tags: php, oop, return

this may be a stupid question, but every source on the web seems not able to fully explain the logic to my complex brain

There's an edit page getting a $_GET['id'] from a link.
I got a function on my class elaborating this one to create an array of values from the database which must fill the form fields to edit datas. The short part of this code:

```
public function prel() {
    $this->id= $_GET['id'];
}




public function EditDb () {

    $connetti = new connessionedb();
    $dbc = $connetti->Connessione();

    $query = "SELECT * from anammi.anagrafica WHERE id = '$this->id'";

    $mysqli = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if ($mysqli) {
        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli);
        return $fetch;

    }
}
```

This array (which i tried to print) is perfectly ready to do what i'd like.
My pain starts when i need to pass it to the following function in the same class, which perhaps calls a parent method to print the form:

```
public function Associa() {
    $a = $this->EditDb();

    $this->old_id = $a['old_id'];
    $this->cognome = $a['cognome'];
    $this->nome = $a['nome'];
    $this->sesso = $a['sesso'];
    $this->tipo_socio_id = $a['tipo_socio_id'];
    $this->titolo = $a['titolo']; }


public function Body() {
      parent::Body();
 }
```

How do i have to pass this $fetch?

My implementation:

```
<?php
    require_once '/classes/class.ConnessioneDb.php';
    require_once '/classes/class.editForm';

    $edit = new EditForm();
    $edit->prel();
    if ($edit->EditDb()) {
      $edit->Associa();
      $edit->Body();
```

Comment: So what you want? use $fetch out of EditDb() ?

Comment: You could make $fetch an attribute of the class or write $fetch = $edit->EditDb();

Comment: yeah, i have to get the value of array $fetch to parse it's value into Associa (), which variables are the value attribute of the form Body()

Comment: `{$this->id}` otherway it won't interpolate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the full code of it:

```
public function prel() {
    $this->id= $_GET['id'];
}

public function EditDb () {

    $connetti = new connessionedb();
    $dbc = $connetti->Connessione();

    $query = "SELECT * from table WHERE id = '$this->id'";

    $mysqli = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if ($mysqli) {
        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli);
        return $fetch;


    }
}

public function Associa($fetch) {


    $this->old_id = $fetch['old_id'];
    $this->cognome = $fetch['cognome'];
    $this->nome = $fetch['nome'];
    $this->sesso = $fetch['sesso']; //it goes on from there with many similar lines
}

public function Body() {
    $body = form::Body();
    return $body;
}
```

Implementation

```
$edit = new EditForm();
    $edit->prel();
    $fetch=$edit->EditDb();
    $edit->Associa($fetch);
    $print = $edit->Body();
    echo $print;
```

Being an edit form base on a parent insert form, i added an if in the parent form that sees if is set an $_GET['id] and prints the right form header with the right form action. This was tricky but really satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (if ($edit->EditDb()) {
  $edit->Associa();
  $edit->Body();) {
      $edit->Associa();
      $edit->Body();
```

your Editdb method is returning a string and you are checking for a boolean condition in if statement. this is one problem.
using fetch-

```
$fetch=$edit->EditDb();
      $edit->Associa();
      $edit->Body($fetch);
```

Comment: Thanks Sunny, this wasn't my full solution but you gave me the right suggest to make it work with $fetch=$edit->EditDb() and $edit->Body($fetch).
This mechanichal process to innest variables into function scopes is still a little tricky for me, but those suggests gave me the way to solve. I'm answering my own question to post the solution. Thanks!